# why is javascript treating variable as string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the following code why is i treated as a string? I have to multiple it by 1 to get it to convert back to a number.

```
  getPositionInArray(value, array) {
    console.log('array = ', array);

    let i = 0; // why is i a string?
    for (i in array) {
      if (array[i].toLowerCase() === value) {
        let positionOnUI = i * 1 + 1; // why can't I use i + 1?
        return positionOnUI;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Try 1 + I instead of I + 1

Comment: @galvan The order of the operands won't change the result. If either are a string, `+` performs concatenation.

Comment: why not `Array.indexOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a normal for loop and you wont have this issue:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/mowapa/1/edit?js,console)

```
function getPositionInArray (value, array) {
  console.log('array = ', array);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].toLowerCase() === value) {
      let positionOnUI = i // why can't I use i + 1?
      return positionOnUI;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming the array is an array...

the problem is `for(i in array)` that treats the array as an object and return the indexes as strings:

change the loop in `for(;i<array.length;i++)` and it should work.